# Mysql 8.0 table_rows problem

Tags: innodb, mysql-8.0, mysql-innodb-cluster

I'm doing an application and I have the following problem:

I'm doing a LOAD DATA INFILE into a table from a txt file, that has 2 million rows.
I want to see the table_rows of my table with:

```
SELECT table_rows FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name = 'my_table';
```

I want to do this while it's being loaded, I know how many rows the file has previously, so I get an approximate "progress" number.
The problem is that table_rows only refreshes when I do 
"analyze table my_table"
(I had it being refreshed every second before but I think I changed some configuration and I screw it)
Is there a simpler way to do this? I'm getting crazy. It should be exact but I haven't found any way.

I guess what I could do in first place is set up the "Analyze tables update time" configuration to 5/10/20 seconds.

If there is a simpler way I'd appreciate it 50000 times.

Comment: Rather than a text file (how was this generated?), can you use and API for `LOAD DATA INFILE` where you can monitor how much is pushed on the client side rather than the database table size? Even wrapping a file read should be trivial. What client library are you using?

Comment: I'm using node.js backend for mysql connector

Comment: The txt file is given to me by a company

Comment: I can't see a node js implementation however I was looking for something like the C interface [mysql_set_local_infile_handler](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-set-local-infile-handler.html). After all with LOCAL data infile is up to the client to feed the data in.

Comment: That could work, I would have to leave one thread opened for the query load data infile and another thread for filling the progress bar with the results of the handler, right?

Comment: that was the idea. Rather than rows as an indicator just a fraction of filesize transmitted would be sufficient.

Comment: https://github.com/hholzgra/connector-c-examples/blob/master/mysql_set_local_infile_handler.c

Comment: <?php
  $db = mysqli_init();
  $db->real_connect("localhost","root","Siba.2019","product");
  function callme($stream, &$buffer, $buflen, &$errmsg)
  {
    $buffer = fgets($stream);
    echo $buffer;
    // convert to upper case and replace "," delimiter with [TAB]
    $buffer = strtoupper(str_replace(",", "\t", $buffer));
    return strlen($buffer);
  }

Comment: echo "Input:\n";
  $db->set_local_infile_handler("callme");
  $db->query("SELECT * FROM TABLE clients");
  //$db->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'input.txt' INTO TABLE t1");
  $db->set_local_infile_default();
  $res = $db->query("SELECT * FROM t1");
  echo "\nResult:\n";
  while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo join(",", $row)."\n";
  }
?>

Comment: I have this php connector from the mysqli page. But I'm running it from xamp and it gives me Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::set_local_infile_handler() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\esto.php:15 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\esto.php on line 15

Comment: Assuming InnoDB with `innodb_file_per_table = ON`, watch the size of the disk file.